# The type or namespace name 'Int32' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, namespaces, using

My code isn't compiling giving the error:

> The type or namespace name 'Int32' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Why does this happen/how do I fix it?

This is the code in question:

```
///***********************************************************
///Author Name: Harkamal Singh
///Creation Date: 17th Nov, 2008
///File Name: CountryPrp.cs         Component Used: 
///Called From: Business Logic Layer  
///Description: Class File For Booking Functionality
///Tables Accessed: 
///Program specs:
///UTP doc:
///Tested By:
///***********************************************************************
///Modification History:
///Change No.   Changed By  Date    Version Raised By/SRS No    Description

///***********************************************************************using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;


/// <summary>
/// Summary description for CountryPrp
/// </summary>
namespace BLL
{
public class CountryPrp
{
    public CountryPrp()
{
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    #region  tCountryPropertyClass

        private Int32 iCountryId;
        private String sCountryName;
        private DateTime dtCreated;
        private DateTime dtModified;
        private Int32 iCreatedBy;
        private Int32 iModifiedBy;
        private Boolean bisActive;
        private Char sOperationType;
        private Int16 iReturnid;


        public Int32 p_iCountryId
        {
            get
            {
                return iCountryId;
            }
            set
            {
                iCountryId = value;
            }
        }

        public String p_sCountryName
        {
            get
            {
                return sCountryName;
            }
            set
            {
                sCountryName = value;
            }
        }

        public DateTime p_dtCreated
        {
            get
            {
                return dtCreated;
            }
            set
            {
                dtCreated = value;
            }
        }

        public DateTime p_dtModified
        {
            get
            {
                return dtModified;
            }
            set
            {
                dtModified = value;
            }
        }

        public Int32 p_iCreatedBy
        {
            get
            {
                return iCreatedBy;
            }
            set
            {
                iCreatedBy = value;
            }
        }

        public Int32 p_iModifiedBy
        {
            get
            {
                return iModifiedBy;
            }
            set
            {
                iModifiedBy = value;
            }
        }

        public Boolean p_bisActive
        {
            get
            {
                return bisActive;
            }
            set
            {
                bisActive = value;
            }
        }
        public Char p_sOperationType
        {

            get
            {
                return sOperationType;
            }
            set
            {
                sOperationType = value;
            }

        }

        public Int16 p_iReturnid
        {
            get
            {
                return iReturnid;
            }
            set
            {
                iReturnid = value;
          }

        }



  #endregion

}
```

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Question' could not be found.

Comment: You were missing an actual question. I've added one. If it doesn't represent what you wanted to ask please edit in your real question.

Comment: Also, you really need to read the .NET naming convention guidelines. You shouldn't be using Hungarian notation, and using a `p_` prefix for properties is quite the ugliest thing I've ever seen.

Comment: @CodesInChaos now that there is a question, this should be reopened, no?

Answer (score 13):

The error tells you that you're missing `using System;` since the `Int32` type is part of that namespace.

```
///***********************************************************************using System;
```

In your code you happened to delete the line break before `using System;`. This made it move into the previous line that's commented out with `//`. So it's commented out too.

Put it on a new line and the problem will go away.

```
///***********************************************************************
using System;
```